# What is causing model error - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

For some todos, an error is raised for the wrong number of arguments and I don't even know where to look. Below I have added the backtrace but I dont see any of my code listed anywhere. Could it be something wrong with the acts as list gem?

I have seen it on a destory

```
todo.destroy!
```

As well as a create

```
@todo = Todo.create!(external_id: params[:todo_id], list_id: @project.lists.first.id, status: 'active', project_id: @project.id)
```

Heres the class definition. Not sure if it's in one of the dependent destroys?

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  acts_as_list scope: :list, add_new_at: :top
  has_many :todo_labels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todo_assignees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todo_histories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_list_todos, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :todo_assignees
  has_one :project, through: :list
  belongs_to :estimate, optional: true

....
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lists, -> { order(position: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :basecamp_connection, optional: true, class_name: 'Connection', foreign_key: "connection_id"

  has_many :todos, through: :lists
  has_many :labels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todo_lists, -> { where('status = "active"').order(position: :asc) }, :class_name => 'TodoList', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_todos, through: :lists
  has_many :active_todo_lists, through: :lists
  has_many :todo_assignees, through: :todos
  has_many :todo_labels, through: :todos
  has_many :users, through: :todo_assignees
  has_many :scoped_labels, through: :todo_labels, source: :label
  has_many :estimates, through: :todos
  has_many :assigned_users, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :account_list, optional: true
  acts_as_list scope: :account_list, add_new_at: :top

  before_destroy :remove_webhook

  attr_accessor :hide_status
  after_create :create_default_lists

  ....
end


 -------------------------------
    Backtrace:
 -------------------------------



     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/errors.rb:98:in `initialize'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/transaction_isolation-1.0.3/lib/transaction_isolation/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:57:in `new'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/transaction_isolation-1.0.3/lib/transaction_isolation/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:57:in `translate_exception_with_transaction_isolation_conflict'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:597:in `translate_exception_class'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:616:in `rescue in log'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:610:in `log'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:212:in `execute'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:26:in `execute'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:223:in `execute_and_free'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:43:in `exec_delete'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:140:in `update'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:17:in `update'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:380:in `update_all'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.3.0.346/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record_prepend.rb:43:in `block in update_all'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.3.0.346/lib/new_relic/agent/transaction.rb:922:in `with_database_metric_name'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.3.0.346/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:645:in `with_database_metric_name'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.3.0.346/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record_prepend.rb:42:in `update_all'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `update_all'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.10/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/position_column_method_definer.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in define_class_methods'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.10/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/position_column_method_definer.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in define_class_methods'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:66:in `block in decrement_all'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:336:in `scoping'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:66:in `decrement_all'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/acts_as_list-0.9.10/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb:328:in `decrement_positions_on_lower_items'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:235:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `block in invoke_after'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `each'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `invoke_after'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:321:in `destroy'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:303:in `block in destroy'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:384:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:233:in `transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/transaction_retry-1.0.2/lib/transaction_retry/active_record/base.rb:23:in `transaction_with_retry'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:381:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:303:in `destroy'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:211:in `destroy!'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:105:in `each'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:105:in `delete_records'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:391:in `remove_records'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:384:in `block in delete_or_destroy'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:126:in `block in transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:233:in `transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/transaction_retry-1.0.2/lib/transaction_retry/active_record/base.rb:23:in `transaction_with_retry'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:125:in `transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:384:in `delete_or_destroy'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:193:in `destroy'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:166:in `destroy_all'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:26:in `handle_dependency'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:140:in `block in add_destroy_callbacks'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `instance_exec'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:197:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:601:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:600:in `catch'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:600:in `block in default_terminator'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block in halting'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in invoke_before'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `each'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:321:in `destroy'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:303:in `block in destroy'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:384:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `block in transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:194:in `block in within_new_transaction'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/transaction_retry-1.0.2/lib/transaction_retry/active_record/base.rb:23:in `transaction_with_retry'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:381:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:303:in `destroy'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:211:in `destroy!'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:26:in `perform'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:81:in `block in invoke_job'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:78:in `invoke_job'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.3.0.346/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/delayed_job_instrumentation.rb:129:in `block in invoke_job'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.3.0.346/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:369:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.3.0.346/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/delayed_job_instrumentation.rb:128:in `invoke_job'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:230:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:93:in `block in timeout'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:230:in `block in run'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:229:in `run'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:312:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:312:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:213:in `block in work_off'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `times'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `work_off'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:175:in `block (4 levels) in start'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:174:in `block (3 levels) in start'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:173:in `block (2 levels) in start'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `loop'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `block in start'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:171:in `start'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.4/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
  /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `<top (required)>'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
  /app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
  /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Seems its because of dependent destroy only. Can you please add complete error log.

Comment: Can you post your `Todo` and `Project` models code, the part where you define the relationship between them?

Comment: @PardeepDhingra I have added the full stack trace.

Comment: @JohnBaker I added the Project relationships. Does that help?

Comment: Do yall think it has to do with some dependent destroy? I could just comment out each of them and test for a few hours. The error shows up a lot.